# The meaning of Java's DatagramChannel.write()

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, udp

I recently found code using `DatagramChannel.write()`. The code only asked for host ip and port before it connected and then would allow sending (via `DatagramChannel.write()`).

Being new to network programming, it seemed odd that it wouldn't request the destination IP/port. Why not?

Oracle's documentation states

> This method may only be invoked if this channel's socket is connected,
>   in which case it sends datagrams directly to the socket's peer.

What does it mean by "the socket's peer"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DatagramChannel is part of java.nio package. It will take a parameter as ByteBuffer to send to the connected channel.
Before trying to send you should connect using InetSocketAddress, which takes the host ip and port as parameter. 
connect(SocketAddress remote) --> connects the channel to the underlying socket. you can get the socket from Datagramchannel because channel is non blocking io used for read/write purpose. socket peer's is nothing but the remote machine.

Comment: Yes, but at which point do I specify the datagram's destination?

Comment: suppose you want to send a datagram to remote machine you need to mention ipaddress of the machine/host and the port number in which an application is listening for the datagram.

Comment: I specify this in the InetSocketAddress? I see no other place to do so. 

For example, suppose I am in China, and I want to send a packet to Germany. How would I specify this German ip/port?

Comment: I don't know what you are expecting other than ipaddress and port for a packet to receive to destination.

Answer (score 2):

> Being new to network programming, it seemed odd that it wouldn't request the destination IP/port. Why not?

Because it has already been specified in the prior `connect().`

> Oracle's documentation states
>
> > This method may only be invoked if this channel's socket is connected, in which case it sends datagrams directly to the socket's peer.
> >     What does it mean by "the socket's peer"?

The target IP:port to which you connected the channel.